# Why are greedy quantifiers less expensive than lazy quantifiers in regex?

Tags: regex, performance

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed

[image]

---

**Greedy quantifiers** (default) - work by swallowing as many characters allowed before slowly reducing the amount of characters matched one-by-one in order to make way for the rest of the pattern.

For example, the regular expression `.*world` against the string `hello world` will first attempt to swallow the whole string and put it into the `.*`. But it cant, because then `world` cant match, so `.*` starts giving up characters one by one until it has given up the `world` in the original string - in which case the whole regex can match.

**Lazy quantifiers** - work in much the similiar way, except in reverse. They want to match as less characters as possible, and they do the same thing, adding more characters one-by-one until the rest of the pattern has a chance of matching.

---

But according to this article I read, these seemingly identical processes for **greedy** and **lazy** quantifiers are different - in that only **lazy** quantifiers have the need to "backtrack". But wouldn't **greedy** quantifiers also need to "backtrack" when spitting out previously swallowed elements?

Why is this the case? It just seems so intuitive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Greedy and lazy quantifiers are equally (in)expensive when applied correctly. However, lazy quantifiers got a bad reputation of being slow because they can be, and often are, applied to compensate for imprecision in a pattern.

Consider a simple example: `<.*?>` vs. `<.*>`.

When both expressions are applied to the same input

```
<abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789>
```

they match exactly the same text. The difference is only in how they arrive at the match: the "lazy" expression tries increasingly longer strings, arriving at the match after 40 steps ([demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/pV7sY2/1)). The greedy expression, on the other hand, goes all the way to the end, and backtracks once to arrive at the match after only 5 steps ([demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/pV7sY2/2)).

Note that the situation can be reversed if you add more characters after the `>`:

```
<abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Now greedy expression becomes the "slow one", taking 149 steps ([demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/pV7sY2/4)) while the lazy expression continues to take the same 40 steps as it did before ([demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/pV7sY2/5)).

Comment: But wouldnt a greedy quantifier also encounter a similar scenario? By "regurgitating" previously swallowed elements in the regular expression, it is also performing backtracking, no?

Answer (score 3):

*Sometimes greedy sucks.*

Sample `[asdfsikbfqew0787072143k*(*&^(**&]`

Bench

```
Regex1:   \[[^\]]*\]
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   200  /  200     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.48 s,   476.21 ms,   476211 µs


Regex2:   \[.*?\]
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   200  /  200     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.32 s,   322.73 ms,   322730 µs
```

Never, but never, use greedy with the dot unless its to claim the remnants at the end of a line.

Someone once told me that this `(?=.*d)` is a lookahead that starts checking
from the next character. This is absolutely false.
This immediately sets pointer to the end of the string, and starts checking
backwards (backtracking). *Watch out for this because it **skips** over everything*.
It is slower than watching paint dry.

I use to use greedy all the time, now I only use it when forced to, and
I don't recommend it to anyone.

Comment: [offtopic] What do you use for timing?

Comment: @Michael - [here](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b2.jpg), [here](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b4.jpg) and [here](http://www.regexformat.com/)

Comment: I don't think this answers to the OP, because you are not applying lazy and greedy quantifiers to the same pattern. Nevertheless, this is still interesting.